# Run script on Active Directory change

Tags: triggers, active-directory, eventtrigger

we would like to set a trigger on AD so that on a group, user or structure change below a specific branch we can automatically start a script to update our postgres DB.

Is it possible? which is the best solution?

thanks
G.

Answer (score 4):

I know an eventID is triggered when a user account is created.
It's `EventID 4720: A user account was created`.

You can then schedule a task via Task Scheduler.
Select `an event`on the `Triggers` tab, there you can specify an `EventID` and run a task when this event is triggered.

You can check a list of events on https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/Default.aspx

Comment: thanks, is it possible to filter the execution based on the position on the AD tree?

Comment: @thegio: I have no idea, this is beyond my knowledge.